# how to take multiple string inputs using getline()

Tags: c++, class, input

I have to take multiple string inputs using `cin.getline()` and I've written the following code. I tried using alternative solutions, like using `cin.ignore()`, but it doesn't seem to work very well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
        char str_1[25];
        char str_2[25];
};

int main(){
    Node *test;
    cout << "Str_1: ";
    cin.getline(test->str_1, 25);
    //cin.ignore();    
    cout << "Str_2: ";
    cin.getline(test->str_2, 25);
    return 0;
}
```

The solution doesn't even ask for the second string, even with the `cin.ignore()` command.

I'm not a very advanced level coder, so kindly try to explain the solution in simple terms.

Comment: [_warning: variable 'test' is uninitialized when used here_](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sfP5dK157)

Comment: Also note when you start numbering variables usually you want to use an array or vector.

Comment: `Node *test;`  you forgot to point test to a valid Node object.

Comment: Actually, I need this for a double linked list problem. That's why class is named node. This is just a simplified version of what I actually need to do. In actuality, test is a pointer array.

Comment: Since this question is answered, you probably need to ask a brand new question with a better description of the problem, with input, output and a [mcve]. In the code you presented the problem in the code was undefined behavior because you did not initialize `test` to point to anything. Its not clear why you are having problems reading lines or why you think you need to use `cin.ignore();` between your calls to `cin.getline(test->str_1, 25);`

Answer (score 2):

Since `test` is a pointer, you need to manually allocate memory to store the data. You can do this using the `new` keyword. Try this:

```
Node *test = new Node;
```

Comment: Don't forgot to `delete` the `Node` object when you are done using it: `delete test1;`

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for editing my answer